# Where is the math module?

Tags: ceylon

The first import mentioned in the [Tour of Ceylon](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/reference/statement/import/) is

```
import math { sqrt, pi, Complex }
```

What do I need to put in my `modules.ceylon` in order to be able to import this `math` module? It is not either of these:

```
module my_module "1.0.0" {
    import math "1.3.3";
}

module my_module "1.0.0" {
    import ceylon.math "1.3.3";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this example is intended to be fictitious, just like the other three imports below. (I’m not sure if it’s intentional that some of those have `com.example` and some have `org.example`, either.)

There is a `ceylon.math` module in the SDK ([documentation](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/math/1.3.3/module-doc/api/index.html)), but it’s deprecated, having been replaced by `ceylon.numeric` (contains `pi` and `sqrt()`), `ceylon.whole`, and `ceylon.decimal`. A `Complex` class is nowhere to be found in the entire SDK.

Generally, package names must match the module name prefix, so a single-component package name like `math` could only be part of the `math` module – a module name that would be highly discouraged.

Comment: I’ve [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/eclipse/ceylon-lang.org/pull/499) to update the documentation.

Comment: I guess the my real question was "Where is `pi` and `sqrt` and things like that?" and this answers that also.

Comment: Actually `ceylon.math` is deprecated, and you should now use `ceylon.numeric`, `ceylon.whole`, and `ceylon.decimal`. `pi` and `sqrt()` are in `ceylon.numeric`.